# Should I apologize for something after being fired?

Tags: termination, bullying, gossip

I have been working for small company of 24 software developers + the two founder/owners. A lot of my co-workers have been with the company for 10+ years, but there are also some with less years and also a couple of new joiners. I don't think there's a high turnover but I know there have been some people who came and left after a short time before me. I myself have 15 years of relevant work experience in the field.

I work in a project for a customer that makes for at least half of the turnover of my company, so the project is under continuous attention of one of the founders. Soon after joining I started noticing a negative atmosphere with some of the employees. Everything was being badmouthed, processes, customers, technologies (even if chosen by themselves). I also noticed frequent gossiping about other people (former employees who left, customers, people from other companies working for the same customer). My team itself, however, would have a good time, so I would not refer to it as being a toxic workplace culture.

While all the negativity and gossiping this raised an eyebrow on my side I still decided to ignore it as well as I could (surely not to take any part in it) as the project was interesting and the rest of the conditions were good (salary, education etc.).

Being software developers, we do regular code reviews: Each code change needs to be approved by someone else's review. I know code reviews are always a source of tension, so I choose my words carefully, offering help, suggestions, explaining why I think something should be done differently etc.. I also know I am a very thorough reviewer which has already led to tensions in other companies with people who don't like it, but also to some nice feedback from people who do. It turned out, my co-workers were in the former group and I soon learned that they started gossiping about me (I was told this by a co-worker in another project who had started a couple of months before me and noticed the same negativity).

Over time I noticed some sort of tension building up with one particular co-worker who reacted very upset in one meeting. He has been with the company almost from the beginning so he knows everyone quite well and his word has some weight. However, he (and also nobody from the rest of the team) would not not approach me and discuss it with me. So I decided to approach him instead and try to smooth things out, explaining that I think those reviews are important and helpful and that I expected the same scrutiny from him. The talk went well and we decided to have a fresh start.

Some time later the two owners approached me and told me there have been complaints about the tone in which I left my comments being. I left a Slack message explaining that it was not my intention to annoy people and asked them to tell me first if I unknowingly upset someone.

Another situation which caused some trouble within the team is that I made a comment about how I missed some craft within the codebase. I said this in a meeting with some people from the customer present. Apparently this didn't go down well with a lot of team members, because they thought it made them look bad. But again: nobody approached me telling me this. It was only later that I found out in another meeting with my bosses who told me I was again the source of trouble.

Some weeks later I got a meeting invitation from the bosses where they told me there has been more disturbance within the team because I did some soft refactoring of code, which annoyed the creator of the original author (the one I confronted earlier). Also my choice of words in the ticket description was criticized, even though I tried to be as factually as possible explaining what I think needs refactoring. They told me my refactoring and my choice of words would hurt other peoples pride.

The end of the story is that I got fired because I was told I was too much of a disturbance for the team.

I agree that that meeting with the customer was probably not the best place to address quality issues and I understand that words can be misunderstood and some people are sensitive to criticism. Still, I'm feeling bullied and fired for no reason. I also feel misunderstood and that there's no way I can say something without upsetting someone. To me it looks like the owners protect the loyal old-established employees and I'm being made the scapegoat.

I'm contemplating what happened. I want to learn as much as I can from this experience by trying to get a realistic picture of what happened.

So long story short: I would like honest answers (not comfort) on the following questions:

- I expect my co-workers to come to me first if they have a problem with me. Are my expectations too high? Am I being naïve?
- To what extent is this really my fault? Is my being fired an adequate reaction to what happened? Should I have done something differently?
- Should I try and again explain at this point that it was never my intention to upset or expose someone in any way or will this backfire by making me look like I admit it was only my fault?

Comment: How did your work get assigned? Was there a ticket to do the refactoring? Did you get some kind of agreement up-front that it needed doing?.

Comment: I was working on the code for another ticket. Since I had to touch it anyway, I decided to do the refactoring along with it to improve readability/reduce duplication and also back it up with some tests. Doing this I also fixed a bug, so it became a bit a mixed ticket.

Comment: How long had you worked for that company (before being fired) ? - Maybe, your co-worker, who worked there longer than you,  was the "**unofficial team lead**" ? and he was upset because a newbie dares to critique his code and coding style ?

Comment: **I don't think you should have been fired over this**.  --- However, in the future, maybe you should observe who the **powerful** coworkers are, and go easy on them, or at least try to make it clear to them that you want to get along well with them first.

Answer (score 24):

> I expect my coworkers to come to me first if they have a problem with me. Are my expectations too high? Am I being naive?

Your expectations are probably unrealistic. Most likely the problem here is that people don't approach you because they think that you are not approachable and that you don't react well to criticism or suggestion for behavioral changes.

> To what extent is this really my fault? Is my being fired an adequate reaction to what happened?

Probably yes. The key point here seems to be the following: you think your communication style is appropriate, the rest of the company thinks it isn't. That's a classic case of a cultural disconnect. When you behave differently from anyone else, you will run into friction points. That doesn't mean that your behavior is "wrong" by any objective measure, it just doesn't fit into this specific environment. Cultural disconnects are hard to address and often do result in termination or resignation.

> Should I have done something differently?

Observe and understand the cultural norms in your environment and adapt your own communication style and behavior accordingly. That's not easy to do especially if there is a significant discrepancy to your "natural" behavior. It requires a fair bit self discipline and maturity and chances are you are better off at some other place that's more compatible with your personality.

> Should I try and again explain at this point that it was never my intention to upset or expose someone in any way or will this backfire by making me look like I admit it was only my fault?

That would be pointless. The train has left the station and any further discussion won't serve any purpose. Yes, you did not intent to upset other people but you did upset them anyway.  Your best shot at this point is to accept and learn from it and move on.

Comment: If you put the @Sascha's code / craft answer into Hilmar's behavioral assessment, it would be IMHO 100%. I up voted Hilmar's answer because being self-aware of behavior is hard and harder to change. It is also important in a team environment. All that being said, don't take it negatively. This is a just a blip and a chance to learn. Just the fact that you asked the question is proof that you want to learn and move forward.

Answer (score 11):

I was on the fence as we have some great answers in already, but I honestly think they are all missing the mark that is all but painfully clear from OPs post to me.

Nowhere in the OP, not even once (I double checked) OP has went back to HR/Manager etc and then asked "so how I should handle X?" or "I am thinking of posting a new review, could you have a look if the wording is alright?". Instead, as evidenced, just continued doing as before, taking no retrospective of the situation on board. There's no ownership of this situation here at all, just empty apology that's blunted even further with "and next time come talk to me directly" which can be seen as at least blame-shifting, and sometimes as outright aggressive.

So with that in mind, lets answer the questions:

> I expect my coworkers to come to me first if they have a problem with me. Are my expectations too high? Am I being naive?

First time maybe it was you being naive. Around time two or three it's entirely on you.

Over and over you've caused problems, and were talked to indirectly and refused to understand the pattern from it. Many people are conflict averse, whether that's right or wrong is a separate debate, but this workplace couldn't have been clearer that conflicts are resolved by 3rd party.

> To what extent is this really my fault? Is my being fired an adequate reaction to what happened? Should I have done something differently?

Pretty much all of it. As mentioned in my little prelude, not once have you actually shown improvement, despite being offered many opportunities to adjust, with a helpful hand extended to you.

You've actually taken it further and made asinine comments in front of a client about the company as a whole. Your response to people not liking this blunder? "Well, no one told me to!" - passing the blame once again.

I can safely guess that the reason they've over and over helped you along, despite the blunders continuing, is because they were waiting for you to own the mistake, but instead each time you went back to the same non-apology. Eventually decision was made that you are simply unwilling or unable to learn and you wre let go.

What else is there to do? Nothing.

> Should I try and again explain at this point that it was never my intention to upset or expose someone in any way or will this backfire by making me look like I admit it was only my fault?

If you honestly now see how this is a you issue, how you failed to own your mistakes, how that resulted in alienating the team members etc, sure, sending an email like this can help to mend some bridges that may come handy down the line. But that email must be sincere, if it will be another hollow one, passing the blame, you are way better of pretending like that job just never happened.

Comment: I really appreciate the answers given to me and I do realize that having made that comment in front of the client was stupid - regardless of the fact that my intention was to improve code quality and not blame my colleagues. It was just stupid.
Having said that, I just got an e-mail from the client regretting my letting go. He felt I was just the right person for the job bringing in some fresh ideas and challenging existing patterns in this team.
It is a painful experience but from reading the comments here at least I can learn from it.

Comment: @stu the client you spoken in front of messaged you directly, out of nowhere like that? That's... weird. Ask if they want to hire you then.

Comment: He messaged me directly. I forgot to mention an important detail: We are a mixed team of Product Owner, Business Analyst, Tester Architect etc from the client and developers from my company. I made the comment during a retrospective so the incentive for my remark was to improve. I always enjoyed working with the client's staff so now I know the feeling is mutual and his message not a complete surprise to me.

It's hard to give a realistic picture of the situation just in writing, maybe I can improve there, too...

Comment: This answer is exactly right - the employee needs to bend to the company. If they don’t like it, they can form their own company.

Comment: The most important point in this answer is definitely criticizing the company/team in a meeting with client representatives present. This is not something anyone should need to be "approached about" after "15 years of relevant work experience".

Comment: @TomášZato eh, mistakes happen, even bigger than that. Given ops comments here they still do not take ownership of the screw ups (any of them), not in a real way, and that's the big scary thing.

Answer (score 9):

> I know code reviews are always a source of tension, so I choose my words carefully, offering help, suggestions, explaining why I think something should be done differently etc..

- no, code reviews are not always a source of tension
- code review should not tell *how* something should be fixed, but only that there is a problem.
- code reviews are also not for "offering help"

> Another situation which caused some trouble within the team is that I made a comment about how I missed some craftsmanship within the codebase.

- What the ****? If you have something to criticize, be specific."Missing craftsmanship" is very general and unspecific, and difficult to address, and it is also ad hominem. There are many reasons why code may look messy, but to call your colleagues to stupid or unqualified to the job (missing craftsmanship)  in front of a customer is really rich.

Comment: I don't understand what "no, code review should mainly tell at all how something should be fixed, but only that there is a problem."  means. Also, I have found code reviews on my code which "offer help" some of the most useful in my career; the ones that say something like "this function isn't following the single-responsbile-principle, maybe you could consider refactoring to..."

Comment: It's ironic that you call out OP for being "general and unspecific" on his "missing craftsmanship" comment but then state the opposite for his code review comments and expect him to just point out "that there is a problem" (which is general and unspecific) but not offer improved code or offer help that would actually be specific.

Comment: @JeffC: no that's not ironic. The function of a code review is to check if the code works and complies with the standards which the team or the customer set for the code. If the colleague *asks* you to help *or* you have clear indications that they don't get a hard concept, then you may teach them or help them. E.g. I can say "be careful, you don't cover the case that some value is null" or you can say "please re-implement your whole class hierarchy and use reflection, as i the mighty self declared rockstar coder told you in nice words to do and imply that your craftsmanship is not enough"

Comment: @matt: As long as the principle was something generally practiced in the team and the instructions on how to refactor were not super-specific that would be appropriate and welcome, but there is a fine line to cross.

Comment: @Sascha No, it IS ironic... but apparently the irony is lost on you. Code reviews are not to determine "if the code works"... you can't tell that with code of any complexity by just reading words. That's what BVTs, unit tests, etc. are for and should be run before code reviews are even started. You are creating these arbitrary (personal) rules and then telling everyone they have to follow them when doing a code review. I see no problem with stating, "Have you considered an array here for performance?" vs "There's a performance issue here" and then letting them go figure it out on their own...

Comment: @Sascha I wouldn't go off and spend hours writing code for someone unrequested but I would point out a potential issue and give them enough details, context, and pointers for potential solutions so they aren't left trying to figure out my point.

Comment: @Jeffc: and that would be absolutely fine. What set me off in the original post was the tone in which the OP described the review process. It seemed they have a lot of required changes where they needed to explain why they have a problem. And that is the symptom which makes me feel that maybe their code review was a little to opinionated, no matter how much they dress it up. My experience is that 80%-90% of my comments in code reviews are accepted and only a very minor part requires any explanation, and much more seldom results in tension, even in heterogeneous teams.

Answer (score 5):

> I expect my coworkers to come to me first if they have a problem with
> me. Are my expectations too high? Am I being naive?

No, but not every workplace will work the way you want it to.  I have had it explained to me as you need stuff, but you also need fluff. This seems like a very fluffy workplace. You are unlikely to create a workplace environment based on your expectations on your own.

> To what extent is this really my fault? Is my being fired an adequate
> reaction to what happened? Should I have done something differently?

It's your fault in that you had control over the outcome.  It's not your fault that your workplace was filled with petty squabbling and complaining.  But here's the thing:  you knew this already.  You thought you could overcome the atmosphere with reasonable requests.  But unreasonable environments don't respond well to reasonable requests.

> Should I try and again explain at this point that it was never my
> intention to upset or expose someone in any way or will this backfire
> by making me look like I admit it was only my fault?

No.  What would this accomplish?   You tried this once and got fired over it.  Anything you do will just make them feel justified that you never "got it."

Now of course we are only hearing this from your side.  It is also possible you are just insufferable.  I urge you to look at future interactions with an eye towards that it just might be you who is being unreasonable.

Find someplace to work that isn't like this OR learn to get along with bad cultures.

Comment: I could use this in my own interactions - `unreasonable environments don't respond well to reasonable requests`. I side with OP and I think the fact that he continued the way he did is that he saw the others as being reasonable and possible to change. OP viewed his colleagues in a positive light.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer - No**

Longer answer:

If it was a PIP or part of disciplinary process, sure - apologize if you did something wrong. But it isn't, you've already been fired. At this point all you should do is shake the hand of your Boss, and leave with your head held high.

You gain nothing by apologizing - you aren't going to get your Job back, you aren't going to get unfired. Some might say that the likelyhood that you work with your now ex-coworkers in future is somewhat high and so from that perspective one might consider apologizing.

But look at what is on the opposite side - there's the potential to open old wounds, if you apologize for the wrong thing, they will think you aren't really repentant or don't understand what you did wrong (which will hurt you in the long run way more).

Simply walk away - but should you bump into anyone, be civil in the future.